# JQuery - Showing a div on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseleave, mouseenter

I've created the following HTML. The yellow boxes contains image thumbnails. When I mouseover a thumbnail it show a view link on top of the thumbnail.

But if I move the mouse fast I'm getting the link div to flicker.

Here is the code - you can copy and paste it as html and test it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.divImage').mouseenter(function () {
                var vl = $('#viewlink');
                var vlpos = $(this).position();
                vl.css({ 'top': (vlpos.top + ($(this).height() - vl.height())), 'left': vlpos.left, position: 'absolute' });
                vl.fadeTo('1', 0.5);
                vl.css('display', 'block');
            });

            $('.divImage').mouseleave(function (event) {
                if (event.toElement.id != 'viewlink') {
                    var vl = $('#viewlink');
                    vl.fadeTo('1', 0.0, function () {
                        vl.css('display', 'block');
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#viewlink').mouseleave(function (event) {
                $(this).fadeTo('1', 0.0, function () {
                    $(this).css('display', 'block');
                });

            });
        });        
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divImage
        {
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewlink" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; display: none; background-color: gray;
        text-align: center; line-height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; z-index: 1000;">
        <a href="Javscript:;" style="text-decoration: underline">View</a></div>
    <div style="width: 398px; height: 518px; border: 1px solid #DADADA; float: left;
        overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden">
        <div style="width: 378px; height: 278px; margin: 10px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <table style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="height: 20px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="height: 20px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="height: 20px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="height: 20px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="divImage" style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also mouseleave is not getting called in FF 4.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the link to fade in when pic is entered and fade out when pic is left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running into a buildup in the animation queue. Prevent this by calling [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) prior to any additional animation calls.

Your edited code (note the addition of `stop()` before each `fadeTo()`):

```
$('.divImage').mouseenter(function () {
            var vl = $('#viewlink');
            var vlpos = $(this).position();
            vl.css({ 'top': (vlpos.top + ($(this).height() - vl.height())), 'left': vlpos.left, position: 'absolute' });
            vl.stop(true,true).fadeTo('1', 0.5);
            vl.css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.divImage').mouseleave(function (event) {
            if (event.toElement.id != 'viewlink') {
                var vl = $('#viewlink');
                vl.stop(true,true).fadeTo('1', 0.0, function () {
                    vl.css('display', 'block');
                });
            }
        });

        $('#viewlink').mouseleave(function (event) {
            $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('1', 0.0, function () {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
            });

});
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @NLV Also see @Sparky672's answer about `hover()`. It combines the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` methods.

Answer (score 3):

`hover()` works much better without the flicker.

```
$('.divImage').hover(enter, leave);

function enter() { // mouse enter
    var vl = $('#viewlink');
    var vlpos = $(this).position();
    vl.css({ 'top': (vlpos.top + ($(this).height() - vl.height())), 'left': vlpos.left, position: 'absolute' });
    vl.fadeTo('1', 0.5);
    vl.css('display', 'block');
};

function leave(event) { // mouse leave
if (event.toElement.id != 'viewlink') {
         var vl = $('#viewlink');
         vl.fadeTo('1', 0.0, function () {
         vl.css('display', 'block');
       });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the css attribute "visibility":

`$(".element").addClass("visible");`

where

`.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.visible { visibility: visible; }`

Hope this helps!
NS